# Update a UITableview from a different view when both views visible at once

Tags: xcode, ipad, uitableview

Looking at my **iPad** app, I have several containerviews.  Containerviews enable me to show **all four iphone views on a single iPad screen simultaneously**. One view, called TrackingViewController, has a UITableView on it (called **table**) that I want to refresh from a button on a second view controller (MainViewController) which is also visible on the same iPad screen.  I call the code

```
 TrackingViewController *trackView = [[TrackingViewController alloc] init];
    [trackView.view setNeedsDisplay];
    [trackView.table reloadData];
```

at the end of the IBAction for the button in MainViewController, the data transfers perfectly, but the table itself on TrackingViewController does not **visually** update to show this data.

If I then manually initiate a completely different modal view controller and dismiss it on TrackingViewController when the app is running on iPad then the data shows up.  How do I make the view or data on TrackingViewController automatically update **visually** when the button is pressed on MainViewController?
[image]

iPad Simulator may help.
[image]

Comment: Sorry Please try to explain it more clearly

Comment: Edited: As precise as I believe I can get.

Comment: That green and blue are so calming unlike this problem I can't solve.

Comment: This isn't really the place to be offering people cash incentives. There's a reputation based bounty system though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using NSNotificationCenter by utilizing the following post:

[Calling a function from a different view controller for iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388990/calling-a-function-from-a-different-view-controller-for-iphone)

In my case, calling a function that only included [table reloadData]; wouldn't work, but calling my performFetch function did (which also called [table reloadData]; at the end of it).

Answer (score 0):

I also dont understand your question..

The only thing I see is, you want to update two UITableViews but in your code you are only reloading Data of one TableView?!?

[trackView.table reloadData];
[otherTable reloadData];

But I realy dont understand your question....

If your other TableView is in another class, just try something like this...

In TrackingViewController.h:

```
- (void)refreshMyTable;
```

In TrackingViewController.m:

```
- (void)refreshMyTable{
      [table reloadData];
}
```

In your MainViewController.m Action, that should refreshes both Tables:

```
- (IBAction)theRefreshingAction{
     TrackingViewController *trackView = [[TrackingViewController alloc] init];
     [trackView refreshMyTable]; //This refreshes Table in trackView
     [mainViewTable reloadData]; //This in MainView
}
```

Comment: The big beautiful picture shows only one table, which I am trying to visually reload without success.

Comment: [trackView.table reloadData]; as stated in the question serves the same function as your suggestion [trackView refreshMyTable];  I tried it anyway with no success. There is no table on the main view, just a button.