# Calling method from other controller

Tags: ios, function, call

I know other similar questions have been asked on SO, but I have been through them and their suggestions, and just cant get this to work at all.

I have a view controller with associated h and m files, and these access another h and m file (not a view controller).

This other called file needs to call a function back on its parent when it is finished, but I cant get it to call a function back in the parent.

Code snippets:

ParentViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
....
}

@end
```

ParentViewController.m:

```
#import "ParentViewController.h"
#import "OtherView.h"

@implementation ParentViewController

- (void)callThis {
    NSLog(@"this is not called");
}

@end
```

OtherView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OtherView : UIView {
...
}

@end
```

OtherView.m:

```
#import "OtherView.h"

@implementation OtherView

-(void)done {
    [self callThisFirst];
    [ParentViewController callThis];
}

-(void)callThisFirst {
    NSLog(@"This is called");
}

@end
```

Can anyone help me to call the method back in the parent file?

Thanks

Comment: First you need to pass your instance of ParentViewController to your instance of OtherView. Where do you initialize your OtherView object? Can we see that code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a function from a different view controller for iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388990/calling-a-function-from-a-different-view-controller-for-iphone)

Comment: Might be obvious but make sure that `-(void)callThis;` is in your ParentViewController's .h

Comment: But surely, if the user were getting a compiler error message on that like he would have told us. ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, the method you created is an instance method, because it's prefixed with a `-`, but where you're trying to call it, it looks like you're trying to call a class method, because you're not specifying an object, you're specifying the class name.

Second, in your `ParentViewController` class, you're not showing your method `callThis` declared in your header file, which means `OtherView` knows nothing about the method. You have to add the following line to your `@interface` in ParentViewController.h:

```
- (void)callThis;
```

Third, you have to add a `#import` for ParentViewController.h to OtherView.m for your `OtherView` class to even know about the `ParentViewController` class.

Answer (score 0):

So in your ParentViewController.h you have:

```
...}

@end
```

That is, you're not declaring the method you want to call. But we can see that it's an instance method, because the implementation says:

```
- (void)callThis { //...
```

But you're trying to call it like a class method:

```
[ParentViewController callThis];
```

That's not going to work. `ParentViewController` doesn't have a `+callThis` method, so no dice. You need to pass an instance of `ParentViewController` to the other object, and then call it like:

```
[theParentViewController callThis];
```

where `theParentViewController` is a pointer to an actual `ParentViewController` object. You'll also need to add the declaration for `-callThis` to ParentViewController.h, i.e.:

```
...}

-(void)callThis;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want callThis on ParentViewController to be a class method instead of an instance method.

Simply change: `-(void)callThis` to `+(void)callThis` and copy that signature into your @interface declaration in ParentViewController.h.

You'll also need to call `#import "ParentViewController.h"` in OtherView.m. You don't need to `#import "OtherView.h"` in ParentViewController.h since you're not referencing anything from that class.

Comment: This is a fine solution if you really mean for `callThis` to be a class method. Just make sure that you understand the difference between a class method and an instance method -- they're quite different. **Update:** I notice that the OP has changed `callThis` in the implementation to an instance method, so the solution here no longer applies.